# Controlling LED Matrix display with TF-S6UW0

Tags: raspbian, display, led

I am using Rasberry pi  4 (4GB RAM version). What I am trying to do is be able to set the text of the matrix screen using a command or by calling a script (preferably in python). I am using a P10 32x16 matrix display (similar to [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32555371234.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.5f8c6c9aC0FrlA&algo_pvid=11e92a33-6d8a-4d9f-a0ed-8f28dee5cd31&algo_expid=11e92a33-6d8a-4d9f-a0ed-8f28dee5cd31-29&btsid=0ab6f82115828433168452659e35ca&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) one, supports only white) which is connected to the [TF-S6UW0](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32869605383.html) wifi/USB controller. The controller is connected to the Rasberry Pi with a USB.

Though, I should note that I am able to program the matrix using windows and the PowerLed LTS program, which is not the solution I want as I want it to run on Rasbian and using commands, not GUI's.

So far, I have tried many libraries including:

1. [rpi-rgb-led-matrix](https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix)
2. [led-matrix-controller](https://github.com/xer0design/led-matrix-controller)
3. [rpi-fb-matrix](https://github.com/adafruit/rpi-fb-matrix)
4. [p10-led-panel](https://github.com/rephus/p10-led-panel)

Though, none seemed to change the display's text.

Comment: Hello Panagiotis Iatrou, Welcome and nice to meet you. Ah, let me see. I googled and found your toy interesting. But I could not find any specification or user guide of the display controller.  Can you give us a link please?  Best Regards, Yours sincerely, Cheers. 
References: (1) AliBaba - WIFI USB-disk TF-S6UW0 LED Control Card P10 Single Dual Color Display Controller - US$10
https://jxjic.en.alibaba.com/product/60796953731-806546470/WIFI_USB_disk_TF_S6UW0_LED_Control_Card_P10_Single_Dual_Color_Display_Controller.html, / to continue, ...

Comment: (2) YouTube TF-S6UW type Wifi card reset used in LED displays - 2018sep07 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7n2gRJX8yY. - End of comment -

Comment: I googled and found similar toys, but not exactly yours: (1) Wifi and USB communication port LED sign controller TF-S6UW/TF-S5UW Model: TF-S6UW USD 32.00    
http://ec086.com/wifi_and_USB_communication_port_LED_sign_controller_TF-S6UW-TF-S5UW20160603092124.html, (2) 
TF-S6UW TF-S5UW LED Control Card - US$22
https://www.led-card-china.com/tf-s6uw-tf-s5uw-led-display-control-card-with-wifi-usb-port.html.

Comment: I also didn't find any guide on this toy and that's why I am asking the question. As I mentioned though, I am able to use it with Windows and the PowerLed app, but thats not the solution I want since it must run on radbian and by using commands or scripts

Comment: I see. No wonder the four listed libraries won't work, because they are not for WiFi control LED display. I guess you should use the "WiFi iLed TF Series" user guides provided by the controller IC manufacturer "iled.com". I casually googled and found a couple of seemingly useful references, but not for your model TF-S6UW0: (1) TF Wifi Control Cards TF-S6UW0 Data Sheet - iled
https://www.iled.com/class/INNOVAEditor/assets/YeniDatasheets/TF-Cards.pdf

(2) TF-QB Series WIFI communication instructions
http://en.led595.com/handler.ashx?dId=62. / to continue, ...

Comment: As the use guide says, you must first connect to iLed's WiFi network: (1) WiFi signal is: "TF-WIFI-QBXXXX", Password: "88888888". So I guess you already know how to connect to the TF-WIFI network using Windows?

Comment: This guide is targeted for use with the app they provide. There doesn't seem to be support for coding it yourself : /

Comment: So I guess the only way around it is to just connect the matrix display directly to the GPIO's?

Comment: Ah, crazy hackers can.

Comment: I guess you LED Matrix controller is similar to another 8x8 LED matrix which I used only SPI protocol. I remember I didn't use any driver but just SPI. Your LED matrix uses something called Hub12 which I have never heard of. I guess the Arduino hackers know more about it. References: "User Manual of 32*16 LED Matrix Panel White(AD026)":
https://www.auselectronicsdirect.com.au/assets/files/TA0094%20and%20TA0095%20user%20manual.pdf. There is a demo code in the manual..  You can see that it is not that completed.